# Air for Android - App.xml parsing error

Tags: android, android-intent, air

I'm working with Flash CS 6 and Adobe Air 3.5 to build an app for Android.
I would like to register my app for the **share via menu** to receive content from other apps. (Everytime a text or link is selected for sharing, my app should be listed in that menu)

There must be something wrong with my app.xml because by trying to install the app I receive a "parsing error" message.

Below is the Android manifest part. What is wrong with it? (I took the code from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html))

```
 <android> 
        <manifestAdditions> 
          <![CDATA[ 
             <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                    <application> 
                        <activity> 
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
                        </activity> 
                    </application> 
                </manifest> 
            ]]> 
        </manifestAdditions> 
      </android>
```

The complete app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.5">
  <id>com.helloworld.android</id>
  <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
  <filename>helloworld</filename>
  <name>helloworld</name>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>helloworld.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
    <renderMode>auto</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
    <maximizable>true</maximizable>
    <minimizable>true</minimizable>
    <resizable>true</resizable>
  </initialWindow>
  <icon>
    <image36x36>AppIconsForPublish/helloworld_36x.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>AppIconsForPublish/helloworld_48x.png</image48x48>
    <image72x72>AppIconsForPublish/helloworld_72x.png</image72x72>
  </icon>
  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>true</allowBrowserInvocation>
  <android> 
    <manifestAdditions> 
      <![CDATA[ 
         <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                <application> 
                    <activity> 
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
                    </activity> 
                </application> 
            </manifest> 
        ]]> 
    </manifestAdditions> 
  </android>
  <versionLabel>1.0.0</versionLabel>
  <supportedLanguages>en</supportedLanguages>
</application>
```

Thanks. Uli

Comment: you should paste the entire error message. Try double clicking the error so it redirects you to the line in the file where the parsing error was generated. And are there suppose to be multiple application tags?

Comment: @timmied The error message is not IDE based, it comes up if I try to install the compiled app on the Android device itself. If I remove the additional application tags, my app is not listed in the *share via* menu anymore but the "parsing error" is gone. So how do I get it listed in the menu again without the additional appliction tags?